# How do I reference Firebase Realtime data in a Cloud Messaging trigger function (to use in the title or body)

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

This seems like it should be absolutely kindergarten level simple, but I'm a total beginner with Firebase/FCM/node.js, and haven't been able to find a tutorial or stack that has explained this. Probably going to use the wrong terminology for everything here, so bear with me!

I've made a simple Firebase function that triggers a notification on a change to `movecarday` in my Firebase realtime database. I've used `change.after.val()` to include the updated bit of data as text within the notification's Title field. That part is working fine.

However, I want to reference a second piece of data from a different node within that database (`movecartime`), and include it in the message body. The data is set up like this in Firebase (very simple):

```
   {
  "movecarday" : "Monday",
  "movecartime" : "9:30",
}
```

And here is the code I'm currently using in index.js for the trigger function.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.pushNotification = functions.database.ref('/movecarday/{day}').onWrite((change, context) => {
    console.log('Push notification event triggered');

    const valueObject = change.after.val(); 
    var thisistheday = valueObject;
    
var timeref = firebase.database().ref("/movecartime/{time}");
    timeref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
    var thisisthetime = snapshot.val();
});


    const payload = {
        notification: {
            title: `The car is parked in a ${thisistheday} spot!`,
            body: `Must be moved by ${thisisthetime}`,
            sound: "default"
        }
        }; 

 const options = {
        priority: "high",
        timeToLive: 60 * 60 * 24
    };

    return admin.messaging().sendToTopic("pushNotifications", payload, options);
});
```

Hopefully what you can see is that the `movecarday` onWrite is triggering the notification, and the `change.after.val()` is made into a var and placed within the Title string. This part works perfectly! But I'm trying to get the value of `movecartime` as well, to place within the Body string. *The code here is just one of many duct-taped variations I've tried*, based on various tutorials, documentation, and stacks, to use snapshot to grab the data from `movecartime` and convert it into a var. But every variation I've tried either fails at the deploy level, or blocks the notification from being sent entirely.

What am I doing wrong in regards to the snapshot/movecartime part of this code? Is this even something that's possible within a FCM trigger function? It seems like it should be absolutely basic, but I'm just missing something.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot going wrong here.  Please read through carefully.

First, don't use `on()` for queries like this.  `on()` adds a persistent listener for data and the callbck get invoked repeatedly as the data changes, until you remove it.  That's not at all what you want here.  Instead use once() to query a single time.  It returns a promise that becomes fulfilled with the snapshot of data at he location of the query.  You will need to use that promise to get the data.

Second, this does not put the value of `time` inside a string:

```
var timeref = firebase.database().ref("/movecartime/{time}");
```

In JavaScript, that is literally trying to query a database node called "/movecartime/{time}".  You will instead want to use backtick quotes to insert the value of a variable into a string:

```
var timeref = firebase.database().ref(`/movecartime/${time}`);
```

Third, it seems your function code is incompelte as we don't know how you are sending the message.  But you are not handling promises correctly in your code.  Your function will need to return a promise that resolves after the notification is sent.

Cloud Functions is not at all the easiest place to learn JavaScript.  It's easier to learn in a browser.  But if you must learn in Cloud Functions, you should make liberal use a logging to understand how your code is running.

Comment: Thanks. Admittedly yes I'm a total novice here, your classic "I know just enough to get myself in trouble," usually just within the front-end world, and even then I just dabble in it. Usually able to learn about what's going on through tutorials etc., but in this case it seems like I'm way off! This is just a tiny personal project I'm fiddling with, trying to dip my toes in. 

FWIW, the function is working as intended (sending push notifications when triggered) when the movecartime nonsense code isn't there, so it's close. But 'walk before you can run' I guess is the theme here.